# Owl Carousel & post-types only showing 10 posts

Tags: php, html, jquery, wordpress

I have created an owl carousel and a post type, everything is working fine, except it seems like I am only limited to having 10 posts.
It will let me create all the posts I want but when I go onto the page it only shows 10 posts.

Below I have placed my code.

This is my post type

```
function create_supplier_cpt() {

$labels = array(
    'name' => _x( 'Suppliers', 'Post Type General Name', 'keyworkerkent' ),
    'singular_name' => _x( 'Supplier', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'keyworkerkent' ),
    'menu_name' => _x( 'Suppliers', 'Admin Menu text', 'keyworkerkent' ),
    'name_admin_bar' => _x( 'Supplier', 'Add New on Toolbar', 'keyworkerkent' ),
    'archives' => __( 'Supplier Archives', 'keyworkerkent' ),
    'attributes' => __( 'Supplier Attributes', 'keyworkerkent' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Supplier:', 'keyworkerkent' ),
    'all_items' => __( 'All Suppliers', 'keyworkerkent' ),
    'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Supplier', 'keyworkerkent' ),
    'add_new' => __( 'Add New', 'keyworkerkent' ),
    'new_item' => __( 'New Supplier', 'keyworkerkent' ),
    'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Supplier', 'keyworkerkent' ),
    'update_item' => __( 'Update Supplier', 'keyworkerkent' ),
    'view_item' => __( 'View Supplier', 'keyworkerkent' ),
    'view_items' => __( 'View Suppliers', 'keyworkerkent' ),
    'search_items' => __( 'Search Supplier', 'keyworkerkent' ),
    'not_found' => __( 'Not found', 'keyworkerkent' ),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'keyworkerkent' ),
    'featured_image' => __( 'Featured Image', 'keyworkerkent' ),
    'set_featured_image' => __( 'Set featured image', 'keyworkerkent' ),
    'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Remove featured image', 'keyworkerkent' ),
    'use_featured_image' => __( 'Use as featured image', 'keyworkerkent' ),
    'insert_into_item' => __( 'Insert into Supplier', 'keyworkerkent' ),
    'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Uploaded to this Supplier', 'keyworkerkent' ),
    'items_list' => __( 'Suppliers list', 'keyworkerkent' ),
    'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Suppliers list navigation', 'keyworkerkent' ),
    'filter_items_list' => __( 'Filter Suppliers list', 'keyworkerkent' ),
);
$args = array(
    'label' => __( 'Supplier', 'keyworkerkent' ),
    'description' => __( '', 'keyworkerkent' ),
    'labels' => $labels,
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-admin-users',
    'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'custom-fields'),
    'taxonomies' => array(),
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,
    'menu_position' => 5,
    'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
    'can_export' => true,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'show_in_rest' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
);
register_post_type( 'supplier', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'create_supplier_cpt', 0 );
```

This is my owl carousel js

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    autoplay: true,
    loop: true,
    autoplayHoverPause: true,
    autoplayTimeout:3000,
    dots: true,
    items: 4,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        600:{
            items:2,
        },
        800: {
            items: 2
        },
        1000:{
            items:3,
        },
        1200: {
            items: 4,
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to add 'posts_per_page'=>'-1' to my array.

```
array( 'post_type' => 'supplier', 'order' => 'ASC', 'posts_per_page'=>'-1' ))
```